# Triangular symbol on the left in my zsh shell with iTerm2

Tags: zsh, macos-catalina, iterm2, macos-big-sur, zshrc

I have changed of MacBook Pro and I am trying to set the same configuration than the previous one.

Just a detail, in `iTerm2` on the `zsh shell` on the previous Macbook, I got on the left a triangular symbol that became blue if command succeeded and red if not.

Here an example of this image:

[image: MacBook console image]

I have copied the previous `~/.zshrc` on the new one but this useful triangular symbol has disappeared :

Does this little issue come from zsh shell or iTerm2 on Big Sur 11.2.3?

Which option would allow to make it appear again on the new MacBook?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the part of your `.zshrc` file that defines your prompt?

Answer (score 10):

You want to go into iTerm preferences and untick the indicators: Profiles > Terminal > Show mark indicators.

https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure/issues/331#issuecomment-312845592

Comment: Awesome. So weird that this just now showed up for me today when everything has always been up to date